# Is there a limit to Firebase Crashlytics server storage resources? Is there a charge for reporting too much crash information?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I am using Firebase Crashlytics.
And I want to konw is there a limit to Firebase Crashlytics server storage resources? Is there a charge for reporting too much crash information?

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics is (and has been [since 2013](https://fabric.io/blog/2013/02/12/crashlytics-enterprise-is-now-free/)) free and unlimited.

For questions like this, always check out the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), where Crashlytics is in the list of free products.

Comment: I have already read this page, but I have some doubts. When I upload too many crash information, will Firebase be so generous to provide server resources for free?
Will firebase delete some old information to save server storage resources?